# Best Practice: Package Development - Including other classes

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

Ok, So I am pretty new to OOP and in functional PHP we could include files to use the functions within it.

I am attempting to build my first package, a simple API wrapper, the API I am using has multiple sections for different areas of interest. As an example:

```
GENRES
EVENTS
TICKETS
```

Currently, I have my package working with a file structure similar to this:

```
MYNAME
 - MYPACKAGE
   - SRC
     - MyPackageSeviceProvider.php
     - MyPackage.php
```

Now, This all works, I am using MyPackage.php for some simple set up, like setting the API URL's etc. However, I don't really want to put all the sections of the API into the one file, i.e. getGenres(), getEvents().

I want to break it down into sub folders so I have a structure like the following:

```
MYNAME
 - MYPACKAGE
   - SRC
     - MyPackageSeviceProvider.php
     - MyPackage.php
     - GENRES
       - Genres.php
     - EVENTS 
       - Events.php
     - TICKETS
       - Tickets.php
```

I have a Facade set up so I can call on methods pretty (i.e MyPackage::getWhatever();).

What is best practice to achieve what I am trying to do?

How would I almost include the classes methods so I can call something like MyPackage::getGenres(); and it would route to the method in the GENRES -> Genres.php file?

Answer (score 2):

This question is off-topic so should probably be closed, but I can't stand to see you do it that wrongly.

The namespace + class filenames should be contiguous, not with an extra src directory between them. And you you should only UPPER CASE EVERYTHING IF YOU WANT PEOPLE TO GO BLIND.

```
src/
  - MyName/
     - MyPackage/
         - MyPackageSeviceProvider.php
         - MyPackage.php
         - Genres/
             - Genres.php
         - Events
             - Events.php
         - Tickets
             - Tickets.php
```

Also, you probably don't want plurals on your class or namespaces.

> How would I almost include the classes methods so I

You would use the [composer autoloader](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading), and get it to load all your class files for you.